Two questions about possible worlds
What I'm thinking about here are the functional aspects of possible worlds as used in models, not their metaphysical aspects.
First, why are possible words totalizing in the sense that every proposition is either true or false in the world? There are competing formalism such as states of affairs or situations where the "world" is partial and most propositions don't have a truth value. What advantage do possible-worlds theorists see in using full, totalizing worlds?
Second, possible worlds and the competitors I know of such as states of affairs all seem to work with exactly precise "worlds", such that, for example the world where that brick is 8.0000000007 inches long is different from the world where that brick is 8.0000000008 inches long. I can see why this particular feature is useful for modelling, but I'm curious whether anyone has considered the alternative where a "world" is a sort of imprecise or fuzzy range of worlds. Has this been done?

+1 Excellent question. The SEP article doesn't seem to have any section to address it. I suspect that modal realists (a view I find highly distasteful) are presuming that if the permutation exists, then the possible world exists, and therefore, like a model theory, the utility of the representation is about holding as many variables constant as possible to draw conclusions. If a modal realist says there are some approximate possible worlds, they have to accept there is no analytical utility in the claim at all. Everything exists, everything goes, everything matters.

Re your "why are possible words totalizing in the sense that every proposition is either true or false in the world?", not necessarily at all, otherwise some modal logics like S4 cannot model intuitionistic propositional logic (IPL) which rejects LEM in any PW including the actual world. Therefore for the functional aspects of PWs frames-accessibility in the sense of Kripke is key, if a PW cannot access thus see all the other PWs in the totalizing worlds such as in S4, many unprovable propositions don't have a definite truth value which is equivalent as state of affairs formalism...

There is a close connection between modal logic and supervaluationism:
Supervaluationism imagines vague predicates as collections of precisifications and then defines Truth as "super truth" (true in all precisifications), False as "super false" (false in all precisifications), and "borderline" or "penumbral" cases that are neither true nor false.
In modal logic, we have similar notions of necessary (true in all possible worlds), impossible (false in all possible worlds), and borderline (it is not necessarily false).
To your questions: To the extent that the predicates we are studying admit precise specification (i.e., non-vague), then each possible world will need to have some value for that predicate. However, if we using a vague predicate (e.g., "L(x):= x is long" and then we set x = "a brick with length 8.0000000007 in" or x= "a brick with length 8.0000000008 in") then it may be necessary to reason in sets of worlds vs individual ones. If the predicate we are considering is "tolerant" of some variation in the input variable, then we are dealing with a vague predicate.
As far as dealing with partial specifications, I think modal logic already handles that via the "accessibility relation" : We can talk about groups of worlds that share some feature with ours using this accessibility relation and so we are not limited to only complete worlds if that is not necessary.
